# AWS / Ansible - grab an S3 item cross-account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-iam

I have an ec2 instance in us-east-1. The instance is trying to grab an item from an s3 bucket that is in us-west-1, but still within the same account. The IAM permissions of the instance profile / IAM role attached to the instance has the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cross-region-bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cross-region-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried attaching admin access but still no luck. I am using ansible to grab an s3 object from this cross-region bucket:

```
- name: Download object from cross-region s3 bucket
  aws_s3:
    bucket: "cross-region-bucket" 
    object: "object.txt"
    dest: "/local/user/object.txt"
    mode: get
    region: "us-west-1"
```

This seems to work just fine when the bucket is in the same region, but now that I am trying this cross region s3 get, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"X.X.X.X\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: ", "unreachable": true}
```

If I set the region in the aws_s3 task to 'us-east-1' (where the instance is), then I get the following error:

```
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.18.19", "botocore_version": "1.21.19", "changed": false, "msg": "Failed while looking up bucket (during bucket_check) cross-region-bucket.: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: \"https://cross-region-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/\""}
```

Not sure what is blocking me from accessing the cross-region bucket at this point. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no connection to S3. Do you instances have internet access?

Comment: aws-us-gov is a totally different region. your IAM role that does the download need to have a proper permission. read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-s3.html

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan sorry about the confusion. i've adjusted the iam policy accordingly, but everything is consistent in my project.